# entry and loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to write a program that accept input from users multiple times. Calculate and print the average age as well as the number of males and females. Every time I run the script I get *ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero* Also when I use the sum(ages) it returns 0. I need help please

```
print('Enter the required lines of text.')
print('Enter an empty line to quit.')
print('For sex enter M for male and F for female.')
print ('_____________________________________________________________')

# Start with a list containing several names.
names = list()
genders = list()
ages = list()
total = sum(ages)
average = total / len(ages)
# variables to append
new_name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')
new_sex = raw_input('Enter Sex: ')
new_age = raw_input('Enter Age: ')

# while NOT the termination condition
while new_name != '':           
  names.append(new_name)
  genders.append(new_sex)
  ages.append(new_age)
  new_name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')
  new_sex = raw_input('Enter Sex: ')
  new_age = raw_input('Enter Age: ')  # !! reset value at end of loop!

print('The sum of age is:', total)
for new_name in names:
  for new_age in ages:
    for new_sex in genders:
      print(names)
      print(genders)
      print(ages)
      print(average)
```

Comment: And what have you done so far?  This is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: I've edited the question with where I'm so far. Thanks

Comment: That's close.  You have `gender/genders` confused; if you make them like the others, this is basically correct.  Then you need to decide what to DO with the names after you have them.

Comment: What i tried to do was to create a list and append the input to the list thats why I have "genders" as a list and "gender" as the input variable to append to "genders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Thanks to everyone for the help and support

````
genders = list()
ages = list()
# holds the gender ages
genderm = list()
genderf = list()
countm = list()
countf = list()
# while loop for termination condition
while True:
 new_name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')
 new_sex = raw_input('Enter Sex: ')
 new_age = int(raw_input('Enter Age: '))
 # Append the input to the list
 names.append(new_name)
 genders.append(new_sex)
 ages.append(new_age)
 # Male age count
 if new_sex == 'M':
 countm.append(new_age)
 genderm.append(new_sex)
 # Female age count
 elif new_sex == 'F':
 countf.append(new_age)
 genderf.append(new_sex)
 # !! reset value at end of loop!
 testanswer = raw_input('Press y to make another entry')
 if testanswer.upper() == 'Y':
 continue
 # result of the input
 print('Number of Females (F): ', genders.count('F'))
 print('Number of Males (M): ', genders.count('M'))
 print('Average Male Age: ', sum(countm) / len(genderm))
 print('Average Female Age: ', sum(countf) / len(genderf))
 break # exit```
````

Comment: If this is the solution, please mark it as such using the greyed out checkmark. Once clicking this button, it should become green. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
average = total / len(ages)
```

there is only one division in the code... so that is not big surprise, where division by zero happens.

If you have a list o users - keep it like that:

```
users = list()
name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')
sex = raw_input('Enter Sex: ')
age = raw_input('Enter Age: ')
user = {'name': name, 'age': age, 'sex': sex}
users.append(user)
```

You can do `raw_input` inside while loop, without that initial part. Just query, and append.

To avoid error - calculate information after input. Right now - `average` is calculated with zero input...

Final `for` loops - for every name you call another loop, where for every age, you call another loop where for every sex... I don't think it is what is needed. With your design - assume that all list has same length, create iterator, and get elements by index. Then be sure lists are with same length. Or... use `users`.

Comment: Thanks Michal Zaborowski, your comment was very helpful